# VB .Net My.Application.CommandLineArgs

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0) and My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(1) , I pass in the arguments through the path of a short cut like so.

```
"C:\SystemCheck.exe" -p:C:\TrackingPages\ -f:Tracking.exe
```

I'm making this from scratch based off old code, so the -p: and the -f: are old identifiers that are attached to all the shortcuts which I do want to change!

```
My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0) --> -p:C:\TrackingPages\
My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(1) --> -f:Tracking.exe
```

The above example works great with my program.

Here is my problem, if the path has a space in it, it sets those arguments like shown below.

```
"C:\SystemCheck.exe" -p:C:\Tracking Pages\ -f:Tracking.exe

My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0) --> -p:C:\Tracking
My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(1) --> Pages\
```

I know that if I were to put double " " Around the path and file it would work great and fix the problem how the  My.Application.CommandLineArgs receives the information. But I do not want change how the paths are already set up.

Comment: Just an opinion have you looked into: **Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how command line arguments work. If you really don't want to enclose the path in double quotes, I think you will have to be prepared to loop through all the arguments (joining them together with spaces in between) until you either find an argument that begins with -f: or you reach the end of the arguments.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even think of that, must be having a brain fart. The code was written in VB6 which I've never touched and I haven't got to look at the old code, but I'm assuming the same problem may have occured when the original one was wrote and that's why the -p: and the -f: identifiers existed. Thanks again!